# How can i update the "Untitled" field through docusign create envelop API?

Tags: php, api, docusignapi

DocuSign Completed document list [issue screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1jXy.png)

Please check the attached image above

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change a completed envelope. The screenshot shows envelopes that were already signed by all recipients - they are completed and no longer can be modified.

If you are asking about envelopes before they ae signed, this is the `email_subject` property of the `envelope_definition` (you are using the PHP SDK I assume) and you can set it when you create the envelope (you must set it to successfully do this from the API)